# XMLHttpRequest responceText returns undefined, but is defined in chrome console

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a rather odd problem communicating between a php localhost and xmlhttprequest, which I can't seem to find an answer in similar questions.

When calling "console.log(xhr);", the chrome console clearly displayed responceText as "TestText" while calling "console.log(xhr.responceText);" displays as undefined.

The javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
  {
    console.log(xhr);//In dropdown menu, displays 'responceText: "TestText"'
    console.log(xhr.responceText);//Displays "undefined"
  }
}
xhr.open('POST', '/file/directory/stuff.php', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

And the PHP file:

```
echo "TestText";
```

Any ideas to why?

**SOLUTION:**
I can't spell.. it's "responseText".  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's simple spell mistake:

`console.log(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: O.O can't believe I made that mistake.  Wow Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's xhr.responseText not xhr.responceText

Answer (score 0):

replace
console.log(xhr.responceText);
to
console.log(xhr.responseText);

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(xhr.responceText);//Displays "undefined"
```

becomes

```
console.log(xhr.responseText);//Displays "undefined"
```

and code should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this replacement
console.log(xhr.responceText); -> console.log(xhr.responseText);